# Comprobar un get y un set

Tags: java

tengo una pequeña sala de cine, que cuando el asiento no esta ocupado muestra un 0 y si esta ocupado un 1.
Como puedo hacer que al reservar un asiento con 'ocu', el metodo imprimir muestre el 1.
El caso es que le muestra pero no lo guarda.
Muchas gracias

```
    public void imprimir() {

    for(int a = 1; a<=asientos.length; a++){
        System.out.print("f" + a + " ");
       for(int b= 1; b<=asientos[0].length; b++){ //imprime las filas   


           if(isOcupado() == true) {
               System.out.print("1 ");
           }
           System.out.print("0 ");
    }//fin for b  
       System.out.println("f" + a);
    System.out.println(); //salta de fila
    }//fin for a
}

    public void ocu(int fila, int columna) {

    for(int a = 1; a<=asientos.length; a++){
        System.out.print("f" + a + " ");
       for(int b= 1; b<=asientos[0].length; b++){ //imprime las filas


           if(fila == a && columna ==b) {
               this.ocupado = true;
           if(isOcupado() == true) {
               System.out.print("1 ");
           }else {
               System.out.print("0 ");
           }
           }else {
               System.out.print("0 ");
           }

    }//fin for b  
       System.out.println("f" + a);
    System.out.println(); //salta de fila

    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! donde queres guardar?

Comment: Creo que faltaría parte del código para entender mejor el programa en general y poder ayudarte.